# PowerShell -match operator and multiple groups

Tags: .net, regex, powershell

I have the following log entry that I am processing in PowerShell I'm trying to extract all the activity names and durations using the `-match` operator but I am only getting one match group back.  I'm not getting all of the matches that I see when I do the same thing in C# using the `Regex` object.  Can someone explain what I am doing wrong?

Relevant PowerShell Script

```
$formattedMessage -match "(Get\sClient\sModel|Parse\sExpression|Get\sAbstract\sQuery|Compile\sQuery|Execute\sQuery|Get\sQuery\sPlan\sComplexity|Async\sTotal|Total)\s-\sduration\(([0-9]*)" | out-null
$matches
```

Output

```
Name  Value
----  -----
0     Get Client Model - duration(0
1     Get Client Model
2     0
```

Log Entry Example:

```
Timestamp: 11/9/2009 6:48:41 PM
Message:
Category: QueryService
Priority: 3
EventId: 1001
Severity: Information
Title: SPARQL Query Response
Machine: SPOON16-SERVER
App Domain: KnowledgeBaseHost.exe
ProcessId: 2040
Process Name: D:\QueryService\QSHost.exe
Thread Name:
Win32 ThreadId:8092
Extended Properties:
Key - Workflow_cbbdd58b-e574-4054-88d4-1dd7a56dc9d9
Timeout - 1800
Result Format - WireTable
Result from Registry - False
Compiled Query from Cache - True
Result Count - 28332
Query Plan Complexity - 661622
Get Client Model - duration(0) start(0)
Parse Expression - duration(0) start(0)
Get Abstract Query - duration(0) start(0)
Compile Query - duration(0) start(0)
Get Query Plan - duration(0) start(1)
Execute Query - duration(63695) start(1)
Get Query Plan Complexity - duration(0) start(63696)
Get Executed Operations - duration(0) start(63696)
Total - duration(63696) start(0)
Async Total - duration(63696) start(0)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do this with the [Select-String](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Select-String) cmdlet in V2, but you need to specify the *-AllMatches* switch, e.g.:

```
$formattedMessage | Select-String 'regexpattern' -AllMatches
```

Keep in mind that with the `-match` operator the primary thing you are doing is looking for "a" match, i.e., is the regex pattern matched or not?

Answer (score 11):

I was able to get all of the groups by defining a [Regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex) and then calling *.Matches* on that Regex. I am still curious to know if this can be done with the *-match* operator in PowerShell.

```
$detailRegex = [regex]"(Get\sClient\sModel|Parse\sExpression|Get\sAbstract\sQuery|Compile\sQuery|Execute\sQuery|Get\sQuery\sPlan\sComplexity|Async\sTotal|Total)\s-\sduration\(([0-9]*)"
$detailRegex.Matches($formattedMessage)
```

Comment: best answer, allows you to assign your result to a variable very easily so you can just handle it as an array of matches.

Answer (score 4):

The -match operator is meant to be used just once; it doesn't do a global match on the input.  Keith Hill put a suggestion for a *-matchall* operator on *Microsoft Connect* [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=264229&SiteID=99&wa=wsignin1.0).

I'll suggest another way to do it.  If the log entry is in a file, you can use the switch statement to accomplish the same thing:

```
switch -regex -file .\log.txt { $entryRegex { $matches[1] + ", " + $matches[2] } }
```

This is the output I get with this statement if `$entryRegex` has the regular expression you defined:

```
Get Client Model, 0
Parse Expression, 0
Get Abstract Query, 0
Compile Query, 0
Execute Query, 63695
Get Query Plan Complexity, 0
Total, 63696
Async Total, 63696
```

Answer (score 4):

http://www.johndcook.com/regex.html gives a decent example

And, by all means, simplify your expression:

```
^([^-]+)\s*-\s*duration\(([0-9]+)
```

- start at the beginning of the line
- capture all characters leading up to the first -
- make sure there's a -
- skip whitespace
- make sure the word "duration(" exists
- capture all digits after "duration("

Comment: I tried simplifying the regex as you described (previous to creating the nasty one I have there) and powershell doesn't generate any matches.

Comment: I took your sample data and was getting proper results with the exact expression above.

Comment: powershell will generate matches using the provided regex

Answer (score 0):

You can include [Regular Expression Options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd1hzczs.aspx) in an expression, but sadly, Global does not appear to be one of the available options.