# Powershell Regex confusion

Tags: regex, powershell, powershell-3.0

Target String:

```
8AM - 10AM (local time)
12PM - 1PM (local time)
```

I am able to extract the times from https://regexr.com/ with this expression:

```
\d{1,2}(AM|PM)
```

However,i am not able to do so in powershell:

```
cls
$var = "8AM - 10AM (local time)
12PM - 1PM (local time)"
if ($var -match "\d{1,2}(AM|PM)")
{
    $matches
}
```

PS output:

```
Name    Value                                                                                                                                                                                                            
----    -----                                                                                                                                                                                                            
1       AM                                                                                                                                                                                                               
0       8AM
```

**However, when I use the script below in PS:**

```
cls
$var = "8AM - 10AM (local time)"
[regex]::Matches($var,"\d{1,2}(AM|PM)").Value
```

It gives the correct output:

```
8AM
10AM
```

Any ideas as to why this is happening?

Comment: Because you're using a capture group.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1703061/powershell-match-operator-and-multiple-groups

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- The `-match` operator only ever looks for at most *1* match.

  - `[regex]::Matches()` is indeed the right choice if you need *multiple* matches.
  - Alternatively, use the `Select-String` cmdlet, which will be much slower, however:
    `('8AM - 10AM (local time)' | Select-String -AllMatches '\d{1,2}(AM|PM)').Matches.Value`
- Thus, with `-match`, the automatic `$Matches` results variable only ever contains information about that 1 match, possibly including *capture-group* matches.

  - The `(AM|PM)` part of your regex is a capture group, so for the 1st overall match - `8AM` -  that capture group's result is `AM`.
  - `$Matches` is a `[hashtable]` whose entry with the `0` key contains the overall match; entry `<n>` contains the nth (unnamed) capture-group result.
  - Since enumeration of the entries of a `[hashtable]` happens in no guaranteed order, the `1` entry happens to be listed before the `0` entry in this case.